# Why is $10x^3+105x^2y-55xy^2$ considered a quadratic trinomial?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I understand that a quadratic trinomial takes the form $f(x) = ax^2+bx+c$. If the power of the leading term in $10x^3+105x^2y-55xy^2$ is 3, why is it not considered cubic? Why is it instead considered a quadratic trinomial?

Comment: it is cubic.   since there is no $y^3$  term,  perhaps they were referring to the binary quadratic form $10 x^2 + 105 xy - 55 y^2 $

Comment: Note the underlying form $x(ax^2+bxy+cy^2)$...

Comment: It is quadratic in $y$ if we allow coefficients in $\mathbb{R}[x].$ But, given the *algebra-precalculus* tag, I'm inclined to agree with Will.

Comment: x can be factored out.  Maybe definition allows this case.